Python MySQL connector segmenation fault on Windows
I have a clean system and installed Python and mysql-connector-python via pip. But as soon as I add attributes to
mysql.connector.connect

I get a segfault.
So just
mysql.connector.connect()

works fine (of course it doesn't connect but it doesn't throw an exception either) while
mysql.connector.connect(
     host="localhost"
)

gives me a segfault.
What do I miss?

Python: 3.10.11
mysql-connector-python: 9.1.0
pip: 23.0.1


The problem seems to be the 64bit version of Python. After installing the 32bit version the MySQL connector worked.
